# How can I make a program in C# that always checks the condition of a text box?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I've been wondering how I can make a program in C# always checking that when a text box doesn't contain anything, turns the background color of the text box red. Else, the text box stays the same. I've made the code for this but don't know where to put it.

```
for (;;)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
                textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            }
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
                textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            }
        }
```

I also don't want the code to be under user authority. (For say to click a button to check the textbox's condition)

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms? WPF answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986105/change-foreground-color-of-textbox-when-text-changes-and-meets-certain-criterion (there should be similar one for WinForms too - like what I believe is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648290/how-can-i-make-a-text-box-that-changes-its-fore-color-based-on-whats-entered-i?rq=1) found in "related" )

Comment: Hello, You can create a custom textbox control for it and use it in your pages.

But I would recommend you to write some simple jquery functionality to check these above conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event textbox_change or a button

textbox8 is the upper textbox and textbox9 is the lower textbox
Try this:

---This code below is for text change

```
 private void TextBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox8.Text == "")
            TextBox8.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            TextBox8.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    private void TextBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox9.Text == "")
            TextBox9.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            TextBox9.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

This code below is for the button :

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox8.Text == "")
            TextBox8.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            TextBox8.BackColor = Color.White;
        if (TextBox9.Text == "")
            TextBox9.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            TextBox9.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

[image]